# What do you call Copybooks for learning to write cursive

Tags: single-word-requests, letter-writing

Special printed copybooks, pages are lined, sometimes with diagonal lines too, there is a printed model of a cursive letter, maybe dotted outlies and empty lines to practice further.
Is there a special term to call these copybooks.
In countries where they still compulsory teach students to write this way, there are special copybooks, approved by the ministry of education. I've heard that in many countries they don't teach it at schools, but just let students to work out their own way to write faster. (Which, to my mind, makes it even harder to read for teachers, and anyone who has to read it)

Comment: There’s no special term. They’re just generically referred to as cursive practice workbooks.

Answer (score 3):

I've always heard them called "cursive (handwriting) workbooks". A workbook is a book that has instructions for children to follow, where they write on the pages inside. When I was young, we had workbooks for a lot of different subjects, not just handwriting or cursive.

Here's an example I found online: [A Prehistoric Handwriting Workbook for Kids](https://books.google.com/books?id=XOgGEAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=cursive%20workbook&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjA3tqpoaz9AhUeEFkFHXB3CUo4ChC7BXoECAMQBg#v=onepage&q=cursive%20workbook&f=false). It has both print and cursive to copy.